# How to display location on google map which is search by uisearchbar.?

Tags: ios, google-maps

> Hello i am working on google map in my app, i add it perfectly and get the current location. I added a search functionality on google map by the following code.

```
- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
   didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
// Do something with the selected place.
NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);


[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }

 - (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didFailAutocompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
// TODO: handle the error.
NSLog(@"error: %ld", (long)[error code]);
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }

  // User canceled the operation.
 - (void)wasCancelled:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController {
NSLog(@"Autocomplete was cancelled.");
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

> When i type something on search bar it gives me suggestions for the locations. Now i want to add that location on google map. that's what i want to do.

Thank you

Comment: r u get the locaton coordinate

Comment: no bro i am getting only place name and address

Answer (score 1):

GMSAutoCompleteViewController will give you search result in tableview only. To have result in map either use new map view which will open on your selection of location from tableview. 
Or use GMSAutocompleteFetcher to fetch results and show in maps view.

Comment: I am getting tableview for location but not able to update it on map?